# In-Game Voice Chat - Hearing Distance

Tags: pc, pubg-battlegrounds

A key component to PLAYERUNKNOWN'S BATTLEGROUNDS is listening to the sounds around your player.

From footsteps and gunshots, to vehicles and explosions each sound seems to have a hard set cap for distance. However, voice chat seems to be the most impactful as this will give away your location to any enemies in the area.

**That being said, what is the hearing distance for in-game voice chat? Is it truly a hard capped distance or is there some sort of fading effect?**

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a fading effect.

Speaking from own experience!

At a distance of **~15m voices start to quiet down**, but you will still be able to hear and understand them.
I've heard players talking **up to a distance of ~30m**, although I could not understand anything because it was so faint.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: @Hulkerman would you happen to have the source code or web source where you received this information?

Comment: @B.S.Morganstein As I mentioned in the Answer, this is all based on personal experience and testing. If you're interested, I have 150+ hrs in PUBG.

Comment: @HazyKingdom the above ^